# primeng - Select only one checkbox item at a time

Tags: angular, primeng

Is it possible to configure the primeng's [checkbox module](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox) to behave as a selectbox, e.g. user can select only one checkbox at a time?

My component:

```
<div class="ui-g" style="width:250px;margin-bottom:10px">
    <div class="ui-g-12"><p-checkbox name="group1" value="New York" label="New York" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" inputId="ny"></p-checkbox></div>
    <div class="ui-g-12"><p-checkbox name="group1" value="San Francisco" label="San Francisco" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" inputId="sf"></p-checkbox></div>
    <div class="ui-g-12"><p-checkbox name="group1" value="Los Angeles" label="Los Angeles" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" inputId="la"></p-checkbox></div>
</div>
```

Working stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-lx5613).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest, that if you want a component that behaves like selectbox, use primeng's [RadioButton](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/radiobutton) component. On the other hand you can change the behavior of your chceckbox as well:

- You need use the `onChange()` event on every checkbox component to
  know when user clicks on your checkbox.
- After the user clicks to a checkbox, you need to store the current element. In your case it is the `const latestCity = this.selectedCities[this.selectedCities.length - 1];`. Since the checkbox items are stored as string values in an array, the current selected item is the last element of that array.
- Lastly you need to empty the array and push the last selected item into that empty array:

  `this.selectedCities.length = 0;`

  `this.selectedCities.push(latestCity);`

Edited [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-abcbff).